# Parsing data from various xml sources by the same function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, parsing

I want to load some XML sources in my divs. The div structure is the same, but each one has a data-XML property that give the link of its xml file. So that div must provide its XML data. Of course the structure of all XML files is the same but I am trying to create a function that takes the XML and the HTML element then add data inside the div.

**[JSFIDDLE](https://goo.gl/Ms9lBs)**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="data" data-xml="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33538012/file1.xml">
</div>
<div class="data" data-xml="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33538012/file2.xml">
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(".data").each(function() {
  // store element instance 
  var elem = $(this);
  var path = $(this).attr("data-xml");

  $.ajax({
    url: path,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
      parse(document, elem);
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("Error: Something went wrong with loading the playlist!");
    }
  });

});

function parse(document, elem) {
  console.log($(document).find("name").text());

  $(document).find("person").each(function() {
    var $person = $(this);
    elem.append(
      "<div class='name'>Name: " +
      $person.find("name").text() +
      "</div><div class='title'>Title: " +
      $person.find("title").text() + "</div>")

  });
}
```

Currently no data is showing. I want each box to show data based on its given XML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you send a document object instead "xml" object

```
success: function(xml) {
  parse(document, elem); // should be - parse(xml, elem)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do violates the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). As you have no control over the dropbox endpoint this will not work. You would have to write yourself a proxy script on your server on the same domain as your website, so that the AJAX request can succeed.

Or if you had control over the endpoint you could send a [CORS header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) to make it work.